# mysql buscar cadena con acentos

Tags: sql

Hola amigos me podrian ayudar
tengo que hacer una consulta en mysql para buscar estados pero tienen que se como estan en la tabla;

```
Ciudad de México
Hidalgo
Jalisco
Estado de México
Michoacán de Ocampo
Nuevo León
Querétaro
San Luis Potosí
Sinaloa
Sonora
```

siga este query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_pink_estados where nombre like '%nuevo leon%';
SELECT * FROM wp_pink_estados where nombre = 'nuevo leon';
```

me muestra el registro de `Nuevo León` pero no lo deberia de mostrar por que falta el acento en la `ó`

tambien lo intente asi:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_pink_estados where nombre = 'nuevo leon' COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

pero me muestra estos errores:

```
Palabra clave no reconocida. (near "COLLATE" at position 58)
Símbolo (token) inesperado. (near "utf8_bin" at position 66)
```

como podria hacer para que sea la busqueda exacta?
me podrian ayudar
saludos

Comment: Acabo de crear una tabla que tiene un dato donde pongo la misma palabra con y sin acento, usando esa consulta que vos pones con COLLATE me diferencia bien los acentos Select * from hola where dato = 'Correccion' COLLATE utf8_bin, ejecuta esto que sigue y fijate que collation_name tiene: SELECT table_name, column_name, collation_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'nombreDeLaTabla';

Comment: tiene este: latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: No sabría decirte si es por eso pero mi tabla la cree con este collation_name: utf8_general_ci y ahi si me funciona la consulta que diferencia por acentos, proba creando una tabla nueva y poniendole esa codificacion utf8_general_ci cargale unos datos y hace la consulta si ahi te da bien es por eso.

Comment: He probado las consultas y funcionan perfectamente así: **`SELECT * FROM wp_pink_estados WHERE nombre LIKE '%nuevo leon%' COLLATE utf8_bin;`**. Esta también funciona: **`SELECT * FROM wp_pink_estados WHERE nombre = 'nuevo leon' COLLATE utf8_bin;`**

Comment: gracias, a mi me muestra este error cuando agrego collate:
Palabra clave no reconocida. (near "COLLATE" at position 58)
Símbolo (token) inesperado. (near "utf8_bin" at position 66)

Answer (score 0):

He probado las consultas y funcionan perfectamente tanto esta:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_pink_estados 
WHERE nombre = 'nuevo león' COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Como esta:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_pink_estados 
WHERE nombre LIKE '%nuevo leon%' COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

El `CREATE TABLE` usado es este:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wp_pink_estados 
(
    nombre VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

He introducido los mismos datos de tu pregunta. En ambas consultas no arroja datos. Y si la pongo así, si trae `Nuevo León`:

```
SELECT nombre consulta3
FROM wp_pink_estados 
WHERE nombre = 'nuevo leon';
```

#### Código de prueba

**<kbd>[VER DEMOSTRACIÓN EN LÍNEA](https://rextester.com/HMB16143)</kbd>**

Comment: gracias, tuve que cambiar crear una nueva tabla con COLLATE utf8_bin y solo asi ya me dejo, muchas gracias

Comment: @skycomputer2 aunque tenga otro `COLLATE` debería funcionar. Si te fijas en el `CREATE TABLE`, tiene el `COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci`, pero dado que esto se puede cambiar de forma temporal en la consulta, funciona. En cualquier caso, si quieres que de forma definitiva diferencie entre palabras acentuadas o no y palabra mayúsculas/minúsculas, lo mejor es darle el `COLLATE utf8_bin` en la creación de la tabla.

Comment: si, pero no se por que cuando agrego el collate me muestra este error:  Palabra clave no reconocida. (near "COLLATE" at position 58) Símbolo (token) inesperado. (near "utf8_bin" at position 66)